# sprintf_s() implicit declaration warning

Tags: c, c11, tr24731

I have a C code in which I have this line.

```
sprintf_s(var, outfile_ppm, local_filecounter++);
```

Here, `var` is `char*` type and `local_filecounter` is `int` type.

When I run the code it gives me this warning:

> warning: implicit declaration of function 'sprintf_s' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

What is this warning and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: "how can I get rid of it?" --> Do not use `sprintf_s()`  Post the code that appears to need it to see alternatives.

Comment: I need to use it.

Comment: Quick & dirty way: add `-Wnoimplicit-function-declaration` to compiler options.

Comment: What's this `sprintf_s` function anyhow and where did you get it? Include the proper headers and the warning will go away.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: These are the "Annex K" / TR 24731 functions. They're standardized but optional, and in practice only supported by Visual Studio.

Comment: @DietrichEpp doesn't one need the `#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1` too there?

Comment: Standard C99 does not have `sprintf_s()`.  C11 _may_ include it.  Other versions may include it as some form of extension.

Comment: C does not support _methods_. `sprintf_s` is a _function_.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: According to the standard, yes. However, I am not aware of any implementation where the macro actually has that effect.

Comment: @Olaf: Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `sprintf_s` function is part of the Annex K / TR 24731 bounds checking interfaces. However, anyone interested in these interfaces should read [N1967 Field Experience With Annex K — Bounds Checking Interfaces](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm).  Here is an excerpt:

> Despite more than a decade since the original proposal and nearly ten years since the ratification of ISO/IEC TR 24731-1:2007, and almost five years since the introduction of the Bounds checking interfaces into the C standard, no viable conforming implementations has emerged. The APIs continue to be controversial and requests for implementation continue to be rejected by implementers.

Indeed, if you look at the [GCC C11 status page](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/C11Status), you'll see (emphasis added):

> Bounds-checking (Annex K) [Optional]: Library issue **(not implemented)**

The only major implementation of Annex K (`sprintf_s` and other similar `_s` versions of functions) is in Visual Studio. The popular explanation given is that these functions are used by Microsoft *internally, in their own code base* to solve security problems.

Other implementations rely on tools like Valgrind, mudflap, the address sanitizer, etc. to solve the same set of problems, and few code bases outside of Microsoft actually use these functions, so there is very little motivation to implement them.

In other words, if you are not using Visual Studio, you can't use these functions. Fortunately, they are not necessary.

The invocation of `sprintf_s` in the question is highly suspect to begin with…

```
// Wait, what? Something smells fishy...
sprintf_s(var, outfile_ppm, local_filecounter++);
```

The third argument to `sprintf_s` should be a format string, but `local_filecounter++` looks far too suspicious to be a format string.

Typically, you would use `snprintf`, which truncates its output to fit the buffer, or `asprintf` if you are okay using functions outside the C standard.

```
char var[256];
snprintf(var, sizeof(var), outfile_ppm, localfile_counter++);
```

Note that if `var` does not have array type you can't use `sizeof(var)` to calculate its size, and the usual caveats about arrays decaying to pointers when used as function arguments apply here.

**Summary:** You can't use `sprintf_s()` unless you switch to Visual Studio or implement it yourself. Tough cookies.

**Minor Note:** In theory, you should define `__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__` if you want `sprintf_s`. In practice, however, the only major implementation which defines `sprintf_s` *at all* does so regardless of the macro's presence—as far as I know. Things may have changed.